# iOS doens't build after updating modules: Swift.Float16

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, caching

This error occurs building ios, after installing or uninstalling modules.
Android build fine.
If I delete the entire project folder and I clone it again from github it runs correctly.

I'm using React native cli 0.64.0

What I've tried and doesn't help:

- deleting prev installed app
- deleting and reinstalling node_modules `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
- cleaning cache and reinstalling pods `cd ios && rm -rf Pods && rm Podfile.lock && pod install && cd .. && npx react-native run-ios -- --reset-cache`

This is the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Swift.Float16.isInfinite.getter : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      Half.Half.init(Swift.Float16) -> Half.Half in Half(Half-3a3d8c19aad77385773246f31e24058bfb0374d1dca0af72dd8118cd999e2b54.o)
  "Swift.Float16.sign.getter : Swift.FloatingPointSign", referenced from:
      Half.Half.init(Swift.Float16) -> Half.Half in Half(Half-3a3d8c19aad77385773246f31e24058bfb0374d1dca0af72dd8118cd999e2b54.o)
  "Swift.Float16.isNaN.getter : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      Half.Half.init(Swift.Float16) -> Half.Half in Half(Half-3a3d8c19aad77385773246f31e24058bfb0374d1dca0af72dd8118cd999e2b54.o)
  "Swift.Float16.bitPattern.getter : Swift.UInt16", referenced from:
      Half.Half.init(Swift.Float16) -> Half.Half in Half(Half-3a3d8c19aad77385773246f31e24058bfb0374d1dca0af72dd8118cd999e2b54.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'boost-for-react-native' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'react-native-video' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'react-native-splash-screen' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'react-native-simple-crypto' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'BVLinearGradient' from project 'Pods')

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eehe-gjrdsvtxbhmdczgytlhaweozzgss/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app/App normal
(1 failure)
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Did you tried setting deployment target for iOS to 9.0 . It seems that your lib is not compatible with iOS 8

Comment: @PtitXav Yes, also setting `config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'` in the pod file, it doesn't build. But it's not that the issue, because it builds fine if I re-clone the project with the same target.

Comment: React native 0.64.0 start with iOS 10.0. Be also aware that float16 were introduced in swift in iOS 14.